# Filtering elements in nested list with json_query

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I'd like to filter out entries from a nested list depending on a presence of a key. Given the following dictionary:

```yaml
hostvars:
  host1:
    backups:
      - src: somesource
        target: sometarget
      - src: anothersource
  host2:
    backups:
      - src: somesource for host2
        target: fancy target
  host3:
    backups:
      - src: yet another src
      - src: and another one
```

I'd like to filter out all elements of the `backups` lists when the `target` key is not present.

The closest I've come is:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    data: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?value.backups[?target]]"
```

which results in

```yaml
hostvars:
  host1:
    backups:
      - src: somesource
        target: sometarget
      - src: anothersource
  host2:
    backups:
      - src: somesource for host2
        target: fancy target
```

So I've successfully filtered out `host3` which does not have an element containing the `target` key in the backups list.
However, I'd also like to remove the second element from the `backups` list of `host1` (which also does not contain the `target` key).

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ hostvars|
                  dict2items|
                  json_query(_query)|
                  selectattr('value')|
                  items2dict }}"
      vars:
        _query: '[].{key: key, value: value.backups[?target]}'
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  data:
    host1:
    - src: somesource
      target: sometarget
    host2:
    - src: somesource for host2
      target: fancy target
```

---

The next option is adding the default attribute `target: None` if missing, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        backups: "{{ [{'target': None}]|product(backups)|map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: backups
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  backups:
  - src: somesource
    target: sometarget
  - src: anothersource
    target: null
ok: [host2] => 
  backups:
  - src: somesource for host2
    target: fancy target
ok: [host3] => 
  backups:
  - src: yet another src
    target: null
  - src: and another one
    target: null
```

Then, select '*not null*' targets

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ hostvars|
                  json_query('*.backups')|
                  map('selectattr', 'target')|
                  flatten }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: data
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  data:
  - src: somesource
    target: sometarget
  - src: somesource for host2
    target: fancy target
```

---

To identify the host add this attribute to the lists too, .e.g

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        backups: "{{ [{'target': None, 'host': inventory_hostname}]|
                     product(backups)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives the result

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  data:
  - host: host1
    src: somesource
    target: sometarget
  - host: host2
    src: somesource for host2
    target: fancy target
```

Answer (score 0):

In a pure JMESPath way, you could recreate the `value` property doing a [`merge`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#merge) of the actual value with a filtered `backups` property with the query:

```
[].{
  key: key, 
  value: merge(value, {backups: value.backups[?target]})
} | [?value.backups]
```

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: hostvars | dict2items | json_query(query) | items2dict
  vars:
    query: >-
      [].{
        key: key,
        value: merge(value, {backups: value.backups[?target]})
      } | [?value.backups]
```

This yields:

```yaml
hostvars | dict2items | json_query(query) | items2dict:
  host1:
    backups:
    - src: somesource
      target: sometarget
  host2:
    backups:
    - src: somesource for host2
      target: fancy target
```